# How can my WinForms app get the users MachineID or ProcessorID?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the user's MachineID or ProcessorID using a VB.net WinForms app? Any thoughts?

Comment: Bear in mind that the ProcessorID is not unique.

Comment: What would be unique that is not affiliated with the HD?

Comment: @redtail, practically nothing

Comment: As mentioned below, I'd suggest the MAC address from one of the network cards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to get the MAC address of one of the network cards in your system.  This is a unique number  The following routine gets a mac address of the first network card, and then appends the bytes in the address into a unique ulong (sorry for the C# instead of VB.NET):

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
if (nics.Length != 0)
{
    byte[] addressBytes = nics[0].GetPhysicalAddress().GetAddressBytes();
    if (addressBytes.Length > 6)
        throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected length for MAC address");

    ulong address = 0;
    foreach (byte b in addressBytes)
    {
        address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access that information using WMI.

```
string s = "SELECT SerialNumber FROM WIN32_BaseBoard";
System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher oWMI = new
System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(s);
System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection oSerialNumbers = oWMI.Get();

foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mo in oSerialNumbers)
{
Console.WriteLine("Serial Number: " +
mo.Properties["SerialNumber"].Value.ToString());
}
```

Referenced from here:
http://bytes.com/groups/net/411975-how-can-i-get-processor-id-my-computer

Another example to get processor id is here:
http://www.devasp.net/net/articles/display/149.html